# Find explicit formula for summation for p>0

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, power-series

Find explicit formula for summation for any $p>0$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kk\binom{n}{k}p^k.$$
Any ideas how to do that? I can't figure out how to bite it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: combine the alternating part and p exponentiated part and you will get something that looks like the binomial theorem. Maybe you can combine the coefficient of k into the binomial coefficient, aka the combination function?

Comment: Hint. Note that $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ for $1\leq k\leq n$

Comment: Can you give me another hint? I still don't see what to do next after this step.

Comment: Look at $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k$ and differentiate both sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Normally I would flag this as a duplicate, since I'm *sure* it's been asked before, but approach0 is down right now and some googling around hasn't actually brought it up...

We know from the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k = (1+x)^n.$$

Differentiating both sides, we find

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k} x^{k-1} = n(1+x)^{n-1}$$

If we multiply both sides by $x$ and evaluate at $x = -p$, we find

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k} (-p)^k = (-p)n(1-p)^{n-1}$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 3):

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n}&\color{blue}{(-1)^kk\binom{n}{k}p^k}\\
> &=n\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^k\tag{1}\\
> &=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-1}{k}p^{k+1}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-np(1-p)^{n-1}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (2) we shift the index to start with $k=0$.
- In (3) we factor out $-p$ and apply the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
(1-x)^n &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-x)^k
\\
-n(1-x)^{n-1} &= -\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} k (-x)^{k-1}
& \text{differentiate w.r.t. $x$}
\\
-nx(1-x)^{n-1} &= \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} k (-x)^k
& \text{multiply by $x$}
\end{align}